# Dismissing modal vc controller B makes original vc controller A show in incorrect orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, screen-orientation

I have a landscape (right and left supported, right is the first in the list) only app.

1. "Base" view controller A shows in landscape right.
2. User rotates device to landscape left, and the UI flings rotates with it to landscape left.
3. User opens controller B (using `self.present(viewcontroller, animated: true) {}`), which correctly shows in landscape left.
4. User closes controller B, (`self.dismiss`) and this goes back to controller A. However controller A is now in **landscape right**. It should have been landscape left.

What is the problem here? Is this a bug? Possible workarounds?

**Update:**
I think I found the reason for this. I had implemented this in controller A:

```
override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation : UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight
}
```

I removed that and things seem ok! Will run for a while, see if nothing else breaks.

Comment: mention some code here ?

Comment: I think I found the culprit; updated question.

Comment: did you check that method is called while pop back to controller A ?